# Python creates corrupt files of excel when I run my code. How can I save the files without corrupting the file?

Tags: python, excel, compare, save, corrupt

I'm trying to write a python code that essentially compares two excel files in 4 specific spreadsheets named the same in both files. After comparing, it will replace the values if there are differences, otherwise it will do nothing and proceed onwards. The next step is to run a macro that is within the excel file. Once the loop is done, a new excel file is created and from there I must replace two spreadsheets with those in a new file called "reconciliation."

It sounds like simple python coding, however, I'm stuck at the first part because my python code is creating a file that is completely corrupted and not openable with the error message:
[image: Excel displayed error]

Here is my code that I'm working with.

```
import openpyxl as xl
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# open file dialogs to select the excel files
file_path1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select the first Excel file',
                                        filetypes=[('Excel files', '*.xlsm')])
file_path2 = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select the second Excel file',
                                        filetypes=[('Excel files', '*.xlsm')])

wb1 = xl.load_workbook(file_path1, keep_vba=True)
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(file_path2, keep_vba=True)

for sheet_name in wb1.sheetnames:
    sheet1 = wb1[sheet_name]
    sheet2 = wb2[sheet_name]
    # get the number of rows and columns in the worksheet
    max_row = max(sheet1.max_row, sheet2.max_row)
    max_col = max(sheet1.max_column, sheet2.max_column)
    # loop through each row in the worksheet
    for row in range(1, max_row+1):
        # loop through each cell in the row
        for col in range(1, max_col+1):
            # get the values of the corresponding cells in the two worksheets
            cell1 = sheet1.cell(row=row, column=col).value
            cell2 = sheet2.cell(row=row, column=col).value
            if cell1 != cell2:
                # if the values are different, ask the user if they want to replace the sheet
                answer = input(f"Do you want to replace the sheet '{sheet_name}' in the second file with the sheet from the first file? (Y/N) ")
                if answer.lower() == 'y':
                    new_sheet = wb2.create_sheet(title=sheet_name)
                    for row in sheet1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                        new_sheet.append(row)
                    new_sheet.title = sheet_name
                    del wb2[sheet_name]
                # break out of the loops, since a difference has already been found
                break
        else:
            # continue to the next row
            continue
        # break out of the loops, since we already found a difference
        break

file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_path1)
new_file_path = file_name + "_updated.xlsm"

new_workbook = xl.Workbook()

for sheet_name in wb1.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb1[sheet_name]
    new_sheet = new_workbook.create_sheet(sheet_name)
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        new_row = []
        for cell in row:
            new_row.append(cell.value)
        new_sheet.append(new_row)

new_workbook.save(new_file_path)

# Run the Macro2 in the updated Excel file
# xl = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# xl.Visible = True
# xl.Workbooks.Open(new_file_path)
# xl.Application.Run("Macro2")
# xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges=True)
# xl.Quit()

#if input == "y":
#    print("'{sheet_name}' values replaced and new file saved as {}".format(sheet_name, new_file_path))
#else:
#    print("No changes were made")
```

I've tried numerous workarounds such as not creating a new file and having the code overwrite the original files. However it seems that my code of comparing and replacing is messing up with the excel files. It will also corrupt the original files.
I would appreciate any pointers. I've searched online and on stackoverflow for similar issues but their solutions do not work for mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the original block of code to save a new file, this alternative seems to fix the issue:

```
# create and save an updated file 
new_file_path = file_path1 + "_updated.xlsm"
shutil.copyfile(file_path1, new_file_path)
```

Make sure to import shutil first

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't you want to delete the old sheet *before* you create the new?

Instead of this:

```
                new_sheet = wb2.create_sheet(title=sheet_name)
                for row in sheet1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                    new_sheet.append(row)
                new_sheet.title = sheet_name
                del wb2[sheet_name]
```

Shouldn't you have this:

```
                del wb2[sheet_name]                    
                new_sheet = wb2.create_sheet(title=sheet_name)
                for row in sheet1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                    new_sheet.append(row)
                new_sheet.title = sheet_name
```

#### Assuming that doesn't fix your problem, have you tried writing the new sheet to an EXTRA sheet, for testing purposes?

```
                new_sheet = wb2.create_sheet(title="TEST "&sheet_name)
                for row in sheet1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                    new_sheet.append(row)
                new_sheet.title ="TEST "& sheet_name
```

#### Why even do you need to write new_sheet.title if you have prespecified the sheet name when you created it?

Comment: I'd prefer not to have the old sheet deleted as it is important to the company. I cannot risk losing it or corrupting it. That's why I create a new sheet. I suppose I can create duplicates of the excel file and then have it deleted in the code. I'll try that to see if it works but that doesnt make it efficient to run. I'll also try out your recommendation for testing purposes. My tests have yielded the same error thus far.

Comment: I think you are muddling up workBOOKs with workSHEETs. By sheet, I mean what you see inside Excel as a single Tab. Your original code is definitely deleting a sheet! 
`del wb2[sheet_name]`

Comment: Yes, my bad. I got confused reading it.

Comment: I tried your solution. Replacing the text code with the one you provided still results in the same corruption issue. Then, your solution for testing purposes still runs into the same issue. The file it attempts to create is corrupted.

Comment: Hmmmm...

Why don't you do some debugging? Test to see if writing even ONE cell causes the error. If it does, then test to see if writing into just one cell, a CONSTANT expression, e.g. "hello", causes the error. If these cause the corruption, then the problem seems to be in the tool you are using to edit the XLSX. If it doesn't cause the corruption, build upwards from a single write to more writes, and see when the corruption arises. Finally, are you wedded to the use of XLSM? What if you rename it to XLSX, just to test the writing and corruption problem?

Comment: I need the XLSM format since Im trying to run a macro after comparing and replacing the values.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. But I am suggesting you EXPLORE what happens if it is just XLSX. You have a problem that people _cannot_ replicate, and somehow they have to _guess_ what's the cause of it. What we are doing is providing a series of steps of debugging, that you can carry out, that will cast light on where exactly the problem may be. Once we discover that, you can use that knowledge to carry out your original task. Have you tried the debugging steps I stated in the comment above?

Comment: I have run some more debugging tests. The corruption certainly comes from the extension XLSM and the macro inside the file. In a nutshell, I did the same tests on an XLSX file and the newly created file was fine. However, after the same run, the XLSM file became corrupted. So I'm trying to work from here now

Comment: I will upvote it and accept it as an answer soon enough. Dont worry about that. I'm just confused as to how I should proceed from here. I cant seem to find a python code that runs and saves a macro enabled file without corrupting it. If you have any suggestions, please share them with me.